# Next JS Export to static HTML always redirect to home page "/" on refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am creating a blogging application using **NextJS** and **React**. I already undernstand the basics because of [this tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started.)

So I tried to implement the blogging application. When I try to test it in development mode `yarn dev` the routing are fine. But if I build it `yarn build` and export into static HTML `yarn export`. The routing misses up when I click on the link it goes on the right page but when I refresh the browser it always takes me back to the `/` page.

Why is this happening?

Here is the Sample Code

**Header.js Component**

```
import Link from 'next/link'

const linkStyle = {
  marginRight: 15
}

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link href="/">
        <a style={linkStyle}>Home</a>
      </Link>
      <Link href="/about">
        <a style={linkStyle}>About</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**MyLayout.js Component**

```
import Header from './Header'

const layoutStyle = {
  margin: 20,
  padding: 20,
  border: '1px solid #DDD'
}

export default function Layout(props) {
  return (
    <div style={layoutStyle}>
      <Header />
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**index.js**

```
import Layout from '../components/MyLayout.js'
import Link from 'next/link'

function getPosts() {
  return [
    { id: 'hello-nextjs', title: 'Hello Next.js' },
    { id: 'learn-nextjs', title: 'Learn Next.js is awesome' },
    { id: 'deploy-nextjs', title: 'Deploy apps with ZEIT' }
  ]
}

const PostLink = ({ post }) => (
  <li>
    <Link href="/p/[id]" as={`/p/${post.id}`}>
      <a>{post.title}</a>
    </Link>
    <style jsx>{`
      li {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 5px 0;
      }

      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: blue;
        font-family: 'Arial';
      }

      a:hover {
        opacity: 0.6;
      }
    `}</style>
  </li>
)

export default function Blog() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>My Blog</h1>
      <ul>
        {getPosts().map(post => (
          <PostLink key={post.id} post={post} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "hello-next",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p $PORT",
    "export": "next export"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-markdown": "^4.0.6"
  }
}
```

EDIT: I followed this guide [nextjs.org/learn/basics/deploying-a-nextjs-app](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/deploying-a-nextjs-app). But I use "Deploying to Your Own Environment" steps.So basically the same structure as this repo [github.com/zeit/next-learn-demo/tree/master/8-deploying](https://github.com/zeit/next-learn-demo/tree/master/8-deploying)

Comment: how your file structure in pages folder?

Comment: Hello I followed this guide https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/deploying-a-nextjs-app. But I use "Deploying to Your Own Environment" steps.

Comment: So basically the same structure as this repo https://github.com/zeit/next-learn-demo/tree/master/8-deploying

Comment: have you tried to use only pure `<a>` tag rather than `<Link>` for the href part?

Comment: @Pierfrancesco `<a>` tag will not work. You need to follow the documentation in order for NextJS route to work.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this by adding the following to next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  exportTrailingSlash: true,
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap#adding-a-trailing-slash

I guess this depends on your web server.

Comment: in build command I got this warning; `The "exportTrailingSlash" option has been renamed to "trailingSlash". Please update your next.config.js.`

Comment: This worked for me, except I changed it to `trailingSlash: true` per the build warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following solutions with no luck

1. Add `trailingSlash: true` on next.config.js
2. Add `exportMapPath`
3. use `getStaticProp`

What ended up working for me was to manually add  redirection code on the index page:

```js
  import { useRouter } from "next/router";
  import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
  .
  .
  .
  const pathname = usePathname();
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
    if (pathname !== "/") {
      router.push(pathname);
    }
  }
```

hope this helps someone :-)